# What does と mean as in スマホを持って歩くと?

Tags: particle-と

I saw a sentence on the introduction page of a pedometer app. Click [このアプリについて](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapion.android.arukuto&hl=ja&gl=US).

> スマホを持って**歩くと**、カワイイ住民たちから様々な依頼が届きます。

My interpretation: You'll get a variety of requests from the cute locals as you stroll around with your phone.
If I were to write it, I would probably do so in the te form, like this:

> スマホを持って**歩いて**、カワイイ住民たちから様々な依頼が届きます。

Does the meaning of these two sentences alter in any way?

と should be a particle, in my opinion, while 歩く(あるく) is a verb. When I looked up と on the [Jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8), I believe it to be "if; when," which is what -て from means in this line.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49062/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the meaning of と. It is *as, when*.

Looking at [the definition of て](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A6) in Jisho, it

> indicates continuing action.

Since the latter part (依頼がとどきます) is not an action of the subject, using て is a bit unnatural.

---

It is natural to say スマホを持って歩いて、ポケモンを探します to mean *You walk and search for Pokemon*.

For comparison, スマホを持って歩くと、ポケモンを探します is unnatural whereas スマホを持って歩くと、ポケモンが見つかります is fine. Note that 探す is an action and 見つかる is an event.

Comment: @konsty another way to understand it, think of it as "and" it just connects clause together.

Comment: @vdegenne - I don’t think that helps the OP. If it (=と) is just another way to say “and”, then why isn’t it interchangeable with the て-form? That’s basically what the OP was asking, and sundowner’s answer above has addressed that point.